# Mod_wsgi , django and apache not working correctly

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Configuration :

**Application location:**  /home/cha0s/hello

**Wsgi file directory:**  /home/cha0s/hello/apache/django.wsgi

***django.wsgi***

```
import os
import sys


path = '/home/cha0s/hello'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODEULE']='hello.settings'



import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

---

Apache file : /etc/apache2/sites_available/hello

***hello***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName blabla.com
    DocumentRoot /home/cha0s/hello




    WSGIScriptAlias http://blabla.com /home/cha0s/hello/apache/django.wsgi

    <Directory /home/cha0s/hello/apache>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

***Question:***

So the problem is it kind of works , but it opens directory just like a list of files , not like a django website. Any idea whats wrong?  I read somewhere on stackoverflow  that mod_python may be the problem , so i deleted it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add '/home/cha0s' to sys.path.

Also go watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

This explains other things you could have got wrong, but since you don't explain what the error is you are getting, hard to tell what else is broken.

Comment: Problem is there is no error. It just opens this  project as a list of files , not as a django project. and i am pretty sure /home/cha0s is on sys.path and right now sys.path too has nothing to do with it, otherwise it would throw me an error. Plus i had other projects on mod_python in the same folder which worked normallly.

Comment: My comment was on assumption that you fixed WSGIScriptAlias first argument as told by others. It should be '/', you cannot stick a 'http://...' value for first argument to WSGIScriptAlias. In other response when you finally tried this you said you got a 500 error. Well what was the error message in logs for that. And did you actually go watch that presentation. It steps you through doing it correctly and explains the errors.

Comment: BTW, setting DocumentRoot to where your source code is is a huge security risk. Someone can download your settings.py file with passwords in it. Simply don't set DocumentRoot and let it default to the default Apache DocumentRoot. Now go watch that presentation.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot. I still can't really figure out what exactly i did so wrong . But after following the presentation everything did start to work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Your `WSGIScriptAlias` line is nonsense. It's a path, not a URL. Should be:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/cha0s/hello/apache/django.wsgi
```

Also, you've misspelled `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in the wsgi file.

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias / /home/cha0s/hello/apache/django.wsgi  
  The first parameter which you specified like '/' is URL , the second is path. And yes i misspelled the the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE but it doesn't change much. I configure it on my server through ssh and access from another place ,another computer so basically '/' doesn't work for me right now.  Thats why i access it through my domain , e.g blabla.com.

Comment: You are wrong that the first argument can'be URL. It can be. But you maybe right that it must point to some directory or file. I just can't figure out to what directory exactly. If i put it like you said  `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/cha0s/hello/apache/django.wsgi` , i get Internal Server Error 500. And if i put it to for example /home , then i just get the list view of my files, which brings me to square one.