# No module named django ImportError with Apache wgsi and Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I've tried to install my django production site after reading [the django docs about apache and wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and [Graham Dumpleton's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton)
I have also spent several hours on stackoverflow and other forums to solve an error that seems quite common (eg: [this question seems similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047369/mod-wsgi-django-and-apache-not-working-correctly)) but no solution I've mined has worked.
My apache server raise an error 500 and the apache log says that there is an ImportError with wsgi

I have installed Django with virtualenv

Ubuntu 16.04.3
Python 3.6.3
virtualenv 16.0.0
Django 2.0.7
Apache2.4.18
mod_wsgi 3.5.1+

Here is an extract of the apache log:

```
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.354853 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360491362048] [remote 127.0.0.1:46897] Traceback (most recent call 
last):
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.354916 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360491362048] [remote 127.0.0.1:46897]   File 
"/home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat/wsgi.py", line 29, in 
<module>
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.380265 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360373733120] [remote 127.0.0.1:46641] mod_wsgi (pid=26147): Target 
WSGI script '/home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat/wsgi.py' cannot 
be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.380351 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360373733120] [remote 127.0.0.1:46641] mod_wsgi (pid=26147): 
Exception occurred processing WSGI script 
'/home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.380514 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360373733120] [remote 127.0.0.1:46641] Traceback (most recent call 
last):
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.380570 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360373733120] [remote 127.0.0.1:46641]   File 
"/home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat/wsgi.py", line 29, in 
<module>
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.380587 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360373733120] [remote 127.0.0.1:46641]     from django.core.wsgi 
import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jul 12 22:42:31.3 80634 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26147:tid 
140360373733120] [remote 127.0.0.1:46641] ImportError: No module named 
'django'
```

Here is my wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import time 
import traceback 
import signal 
import sys 

path='/home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path) 

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "unflat.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and the httpd.conf file:

```
Alias /static/ /home/david/DjangoProjects/static/
<Directory /home/david/DjangoProjects/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WGIScriptAlias / /home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/
<Directory /home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

at least here is the 000-default.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/static
    <Directory /home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess unflat python-home=/home/david/PythonEnv/djangounflatenv python-path=/home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat
    WSGIProcessGroup unflat
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/david/DjangoProjects/unflat/unflat/wsgi.py process-group=unflat application-group=%{GLOBAL}

</VirtualHost>
```

If someone could help me to find what is getting wrong with all that stuff it will be great and much appreciate.
Thank you.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, would suggest you upgrade mod_wsgi. That version they ship with Ubuntu is ancient and not supported.

Comment: From the command line ``python`` for that virtual environment, do ``import django; print(django.__file__)``. What do you get? Possibly do this as the Apache user if you can.

Comment: Are the directories down to ``/home/david/DjangoProjects`` and everything under them, including files, accessible to the user that Apache runs as?

Comment: Hi Graham and thanks for your quick comment.

Comment: I logged in  with www-data (the apache user) and typed the python request within the virtualenv. The response is the same as when I log with my account

Comment: >>> import django
>>> print(django.__file__)
/home/david/PythonEnv/djangounflatenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py

Comment: Both Django project directories (DjangoProjects/flowka...) and virtualenv directories (djangounflatenv/...) are owned by www-data subdirectories are also owned by wwww-data

Comment: Can only suggest you upgrade the ancient mod_wsgi then. The mod_wsgi from Ubuntu/Debian distros should never be used as they are usually very old and the OS distributions do not support them.

Comment: following your advice, I removed mod_wsgi from the previous apt-get install and I Installed it again thru pip. (using the vrirtual env i had created). Then I tried to launch   mod_wsgi-express module-config but I got a new error; and I didn't find any documentation about this error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_wsgi_packages').

Comment: here is the output of the comment:
"/home/david/PythonEnv/djangounflatenv/bin/mod_wsgi-express", line 7, in <module>
    from mod_wsgi.server import main
  File "/home/david/PythonEnv/djangounflatenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import apxs_config
  File "/home/david/PythonEnv/djangounflatenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/apxs_config.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mod_wsgi_packages.httpd import __file__ as PACKAGES_ROOTDIR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_wsgi_packages'

Comment: I would ``pip uninstall mod_wsgi`` again and try re-installing it. For whatever reason, it hasn't been installed correctly, or the virtual environment wasn't activated properly when run. Make sure you are not using ``sudo`` to ``pip install`` it, do it as yourself. Initially even try installing it into a completely fresh virtual environment just to see if you can get it installed and running. Then go back to original virtual environment.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton After re-installing, re-re-installing again and again; changing the owners of the site directories and python virtual environment, modifying httpd.conf and apache2.conf the solution was in installing the django-debug-toolbar. This module is not listed in the apps of my staging-settings but seems to be required by mod_wsgi. It's quite weird and I can not explain this issue...but it works

Comment: Now uninstall ``django-debug-toolbar``. It shouldn't be needed. The problem may have been that there was a broken ``.pth`` file in the ``site-packages`` directory which was causing problems. When uninstalling any package, also try running ``pip uninstall`` multiple times for same package in case you managed to have multiple versions installed.

Answer (score 0):

As such problems may have more than one factor and depend on a set of configurations, I'll display the one that now works for me. I  have also added gunicorn

**django side**

*staging_requirements.txt*

```
-r base_requirements.txt
whitenoise>=3.3.1
mod_wsgi-httpd>=2.4.27.1
mod_wsgi>=4.6.4
gunicorn>=19.9.0
```

*staging_settings.py*

```
from .base_settings import *
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS += ['192.168.1/24','unflat.net','*']
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/unflat'
INSTALLED_APPS += ['mod_wsgi.server',]
MIDDLEWARE += [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'unflat.wsgi.application'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

**apache side**

*/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflatenv/lib/python3.6/site$
WSGIPythonHome "/home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflatenv/lib/python3.6"
```

*/etc/apache2/apache2.conf*

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
ServerName unflat.net
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

*etc/apache2/sites-enabled/unflat.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>

    ServerName  unflat.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@unflat.net
    DocumentRoot "/home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflat" 

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/unflat-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/unflat-access.log combined

    Alias /static "/home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflat/static"
    Alias /uploads "/home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflat/uploads"

    <Directory "/home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflat">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflat/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

ProxyPass /static !
ProxyPass /uploads !
ProxyPass /unflat  http://localhost:8000
```

*/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load*

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflatenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpyt$
```

...and at least, launching the python virtualenv, gunicorn and apache to start the server:

```
source /home/djangouser/DjangoProjects/unflatenv/bin/activate
gunicorn unflat.wsgi --daemon
sudo systemctl start apache2  
#sudo apachectl restart
```